# ng-init and ng-model gives the form a value

Tags: html, angularjs, forms

I'm really new to angularjs and want to use some of its features for my web application.

I want to make a thing where I have a form and when I type on it, the application shows a preview of the content, like on stackoverflow's asking page. The problem is, I want to a have a default value like "title" and when I start typing the "title" disappears and the content is shown in its place. I tried using ng-init and ng-modal but when I use ng-init with the ng-modal the value "title" is shown in the form. I know how to do this with ajax but its really boring to do it for every single input text.

I don't want it to appear as value in the form, if you know what I mean...

Any suggestions on how to make this possible?

Here is the snippet :

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="" ng-init="title='title'" ;>
  <form>
    <input type='text' ng-model='title'>
  </form>
  <br> {{title}}

</div>
```

As you can see in the form it has the title as value i want the title outside the form to be there but the one inside not.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for `ng-placeholder`?

Comment: @Azmisov I already got my answer thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use another variable in `ng-init` instead of modal variable and on change set value of that variable to modal variable value

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="" ng-init="previewTitle='Title'" ;>
  <form>
    <input type='text' ng-model='title' ng-change="previewTitle=title">
  </form>
  <br> {{previewTitle}}

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks that perfect ;)

Answer (score 1):

You just want to use a **placeholder**.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="">
  <form>
    <input type='text' placeholder="title" ng-model='title'>
  </form>
  <br> {{title}}

</div>
```

No link with angular, just a basic HTML feature

Comment: You didn't get it quite exactly, if I don't use the ng-init and use the placeholder the {{title}} value is blank, and it should be title.

Comment: Yes because a placeholder is just used to give an example to user. XYZ's solution do the trick for your need.

Comment: thanks anyway for your time, and by the way I have a placeholder in the original app ;)